# Logging every Create/Update/Delete

Tags: mysql, json, database, logging, storage

I need to log every changes through the application. Every changes will be connected to specific user, but connection can be `null` as well (add new item by remote API).
Let's imagine that some user adds new item. Here my problem starts... :) I don't know, how to store it properly and also don't know right solution. My ideas:

## 1 MySQL record

`id(bigint), created_at(timestamp), user(int), changes(json?/or something else?)`

JSON would be like:

```
{
  table_name: 'item_name',
  id_item: 1,
  note: '' // optional
}
```

I don't know if this method is right for this use case. When I am writing this, I am thinking about `id` as `uuid` not `int`. Could it be?

## 2 JSON

Save record by record to the json file and after some size create new one. Records would be the similar structure.

---

I really don't know what method is the best for this use case. I'll be appreciate for a bit help. Thank you. Have a nice day. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds similar to functionality provided by temporal tables, a feature built into recent versions of MariaDB. You may want to look into that before you start inventing your own audit logging.